# Get objects by value from IntegerField in queryset

Tags: django

```
class Test(models.Model): 
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

How to retrieve an object whose "quantity" is the fifth(from the highest) in term of value?

Comment: Other than ordering and slicing?

Comment: If you want the fifth item: `t= Test.objects.all().order_by('-quantity')[4]`
(the index starts at 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the fifth item:

```
t = Test.objects.order_by('-quantity')[4]
```

(the index starts at 0, so 4 refers to the 5th element)
`order_by` is quite self explanatory, note the `-` which order the queryset from the highest to the lowest.

You could try as well

```
  t = Test.objects.order_by('quantity')[-5]
```

The order is reverse, and you take the 5th last element.

To ensure, the 5th element exist, you may had:

```
if Test.objects.all().count() >= 5:
    t = Test.objects.order_by('-quantity')[4]
else:
    pass # do something
```

Comment: Correct answer, but I would just check for the count (make sure it does exist) and then get the `[4]`. Another trivial thing (Not trying to be a prick here.. :) ) - `.all()` is redundant..